# Thunderbird 60 becomes unresponsive after clicking the "Write" button

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, thunderbird

Thunderbird 60.2.1 installed on my Lubuntu 18.04.1, as a part of the standard updates.

Now, when I click on the "Write" button to start a new message, the application becomes unresponsive. The task manager shows full load on one CPU core, with 402 MB RSS, and 2.5 GB VM-Size. The "Unresponsive Process" window appears, and I'm forced to end the process.

- Is any one else experiencing these issues with the Thunderbird 60.2.1 update?
- Should I downgrade to the prior version, or is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today. In my case, it helped to deactivate my external html signature.

Comment: Thank you @pireba. I was using the internal html signature, which appears to also be causing this issue.

Comment: Update: after further testing, unchecking the "Use HTML" option, and inserting a plain-text signature works without crashing the process.